# Latex tabularx columns not equally spaced

Tags: tabularx

I dont' understand why my columns Y are not equally spaced :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=10mm,
    right= 10mm,
    top=10mm,
}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { |p{5cm} Y Y Y Y Y Y p{5cm}| }
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{C}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}    & M     \\ \cline{2-8} 
        & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Titre}                          & R    \\ \cline{2-8} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & B   \\ \cline{2-8} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & Autres \\ \cline{2-8} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & DATE   \\ \cline{1-8}
    \end{tabularx}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reason for all these multicolumns?

Comment: Because it's a very complicated array with multi columns and rows. So this is for me the best way to do it.

Comment: Problem here is that the multicolumns override what ever setting is being used in the cell, and since everything is multicolumns.... Perhaps you should start by describing your real end goal, then people can offer suggestions on how to solve it. `tabularx` and friends is not always the proper tool.

Comment: I suggest you use the `tabularray` package which is probably better for typing multicolumn and multirow content.

Comment: If your table has a number of multi columns and multi rows `tabularx` and `multirow` aren't the best choices. Take a look at the `tabularray` package. That package has extensive support for formatting complex tables.

Comment: @alchemist -- A major problem with the the OP's code is that the columns' final properties are not sufficiently determined. Switching from a `tabularx` to a `tabulary` framework will not resolve this issue on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is suffocating information about the 6 `Y`-type columns with a multitude of `\multicolumn}{...}{c}{...}` wrappers. As a result, all LaTeX "knows" is that *pairs* of `Y` columns are supposed to act like single `c`-type columns, and this is precisely what you get.

I suggest that you (a) get rid of 10 of the 12 `\multicolumn` wrappers  and (b) replace the redundant *pairs* of `Y`-type columns with *single* `Y`-type columns. This entails a reduction in the total number of columns from 8 to 5.

*Addendum*, posted after the OP pointed out in a comment that the "C" and "A" header cells in row 1 should have equal widths. Because of the table's limited information content -- in particular, because the widths of the 3 `Y`-type colums are determined as a residual -- LaTeX cannot determine on its own how wide these two cells should be. It is therefore necessary to calculate the target widths of these two cells from scratch, i.e., directly from the limited information that's available. How to do this is shown below; check out the calculations for the `\mylen` length parameter toward the end of the preamble.

Note that the overall structure of table 2 and 3 is the same:

```
{| p{5cm} | *{3}{Y|} p{5cm} |}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,calc}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

% For the 3rd table, calculate the *usable* width of the 2 columns 
% that jointly span the 3 Y-type columns. In a two-step process:
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textwidth-10cm-4\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}
\setlength\mylen{(\mylen-4\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)/2}

% Or, perfotm the length calculation in a single step:
% \setlength\mylen{(\textwidth-10cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth)/2}

\begin{document}
    
\noindent\textbf{before} % 1st table

\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {| p{5cm} *{6}{Y} p{5cm} |}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{C}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}    & M     \\ \cline{2-8} 
& \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Titre}  & R    \\ \cline{2-8} 
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & B   \\ \cline{2-8} 
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & Autres \\ \cline{2-8} 
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & DATE   \\ \cline{1-8}
\end{tabularx}
   

\bigskip\noindent\textbf{initial adjustments} % 2nd table

\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {| p{5cm} | *{3}{Y|} p{5cm} |}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} 
  & C & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A} & M \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre} & R \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & B   \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & Autres \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & DATE   \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}


\bigskip\noindent\textbf{additional adjustments} % 3rd table

\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} {| p{5cm} | *{3}{Y|} p{5cm} |}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{logo} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{% 
   %% Use "w" column type for both columns, and use a 
   %% fixed width of "\mylen" (calculated earlier)
   \begin{tabular}{@{} wc{\mylen} | wc{\mylen} @{}}
        C & A 
   \end{tabular}} & M \\
\cline{2-5} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Titre} & R \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & B   \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & Autres \\ 
  \cline{2-5} 
  & C & C & C & DATE   \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However is it possible to center the first row because the vertical line in not at the center.

Comment: @Mo0nKizz - Let me work on this...

Comment: Just one more thing, I don't want to use tabularray package

Comment: @Mo0nKizz - Not to worry, I don't use this package...